# Auto create realm for registered user

Tags: multi-tenant, keycloak

Is it possible to create a new realm for the user after the registration process?
I'm trying to build a multi-tenant system.

Each user, after registration (over Facebook, Google etc), must have his own realm, where he can managed his own users.

Is it possible, and if yes, then how?

Thanks.

Comment: KC doesn't encourage to have many realms per installation. Instead, for that case it is advisable to have a KC instance per realm: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-1268?focusedCommentId=13251313&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-13251313

Comment: but i need to create realms dynamical on the fly. ich have the following hierarchy. every user must have the possibility to create new own users. how can i do this?

Comment: What happens if different users create the same user (same e-mail)?

Comment: It's allowed, the seconod user must have the uniq id, i don't need an Email for seconods users. If he forgot his password, then must the main/first user reset it for him

Comment: Then if you implement one realm per first user, you need to Know which realm log its users in, before redirecting them to the login screen. How are you going to implement this for users Who are not still logged in?